# str_detect: how to test for hundreds of substrings?

Tags: r, string, filter, stringr

I have a very large dataset containing names of both sexes. Another dataset contains the most common girl names. My goal is to filter out all names that contain a common girl name. How to do it with tidyverse?

**This is my best try on simulated data.**

```
library(tidyverse)

names =tibble(name = c("Mark", "Roger", "May", "Emma", "Angelina", "Emma-Anna"))

girl_names = tibble(name = c("May", "Emma", "Angelina"))

names %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(name, ??))
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
names %>% 
  filter(str_detect(name, paste0("^(", paste0(girl_names$name, collapse = "|"), ")$")))
  name    
  <chr>   
1 May     
2 Emma    
3 Angelina
```

The important point here is this:

```
paste0("^(", paste0(girl_names$name, collapse = "|"), ")$")
[1] "^(May|Emma|Angelina)$"
```

By including the anchors `^` and `$` we assert that the strings actually end where the girls' names end thus avoiding to also match compound names such as `Emma-Anna`

**EDIT**

If compound names are also to be matched:

```
names %>% 
  filter(str_detect(name, paste0(girl_names$name, collapse = "|")))
# A tibble: 4 × 1
  name     
  <chr>    
1 May      
2 Emma     
3 Angelina 
4 Emma-Anna
```

Comment: Thanks! But it does not show one girl name: "Emma-Anna"

Comment: SO you want `Emma-Anna`also?

Answer (score 1):

If `girl_names` and `names` are `data.frame`s, then we can use `dplyr::semi_join`:

```r
library(dplyr) 

names = tibble(name = c("Mark", "Roger", "May", "Emma", "Angelina", "Emma-Anna"))

girl_names = tibble(name = c("May", "Emma", "Angelina"))

names %>% 
  semi_join(girl_names, bny = "name")

#> Joining, by = "name"
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   name    
#>   <chr>   
#> 1 May     
#> 2 Emma    
#> 3 Angelina
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If, however, `girl_names` is a vector, we can use `match` or its wrapper `%in%`:

```r
library(dplyr)

girl_names_vec = c("May", "Emma", "Angelina")

names %>% 
  filter(name %in% girl_names_vec)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   name    
#>   <chr>   
#> 1 May     
#> 2 Emma    
#> 3 Angelina
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you want to detect any part of the name and account for compound names, then a `dplyr::rowwise()` approach with `strsplit` could look like below:

```r
library(dplyr)

girl_names <- tibble(name = c("May", "Emma", "Angelina"))

names %>% 
  mutate(name2 = strsplit(name, "[_\\s-]")) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(any(unlist(name2) %in% girl_names$name)) %>% 
  select(!name2)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   name     
#>   <chr>    
#> 1 May      
#> 2 Emma     
#> 3 Angelina 
#> 4 Emma-Anna
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>